# I have a number for the last row of the excel sheet. How do I incorporate this with the range function so that I can autofill some data?

Tags: excel, vba

```
public LastCell as integer
Dim rng As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select the last row in the file", Title:="LAST CELL", Type:=8)
LastCell = rng.Row
```

the user is asked to input the last cell.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 13), Cells(LastCell, 13)), Type:=xlFillValues
```

they are in separate modules. shouldnt they work? any other alternatives to it? thanks!

Comment: the `AutoFill` method will only work on contiguous rows of data (AFAIK). Also, the `AutoFill` method needs to operate on the **exact** selection that is the first part of the range in the fill argument. So `Range("A1").AutoFill Destination: Range("A1:A10")` will work, where as `Range("A1").AutoFill Destination: Range("A2:A10")` will not. Nor will, `Range("A1:C1").AutoFill Destination: Range("D2:F30")`. All that said, my concern with your code is the use of `Selection` then `Range(Cells(1,13)) ..` I am concerned they don't match.

Comment: yes this helped as well thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you use "Selection" to autofill the rows to "LastCell", but don't specify which cells to select. The following copies the formula in M1 until it reaches the row "LastRow".

```
Sub Autofill()

        Dim LastRow As Integer

        LastRow = InputBox(Prompt:="Select the last row in the file", Title:="LAST CELL")
        Range("M1").Autofill Destination:=Range("M1:M" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillValues

End Sub
```

Comment: i get a type mismatch :/

Comment: You need to enter integer values for all variables used. If you want the user to enter the location of cells you have to alter the code.

Comment: yes i did do that. but still i get a type mismatched

Comment: Cells(1, 13).Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, 13), Cells(LastCell, 13)), Type:=xlFillValues

this seems to fix it for me. thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: Glad I was of help! Using your code, do you get the same value in every cell that is autofilled (namely the value of cell M1)? I am sorry that I could not give you a solution that worked for you, I tried a few numbers and did not get a type mismatch... Therefore I did not really know why the error occured in your case.

Comment: yes it did! The cell actually contained a formula and this helped me auto-fill it to the last cell. I've just been learning macros for a few weeks so i don't know what caused the type mismatched.

Comment: Okay, I initially thought you wanted to do something else... I once more changed the code, now it should definitely do what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes that was exactly what i wanted! Sorry i didn't provide enough information in the first place.

Thanks a lot :)